# XML string to be stored as string in variable without parsing by PHP (xml inside JSON)

Tags: xml, json

ts simple but I can't understand where I am wrong. The code is:

```
<?php
$v='<?xml version="1.0" ?><span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>';
print $v;
?>
```

I want the browser to output as

```
'<?xml version="1.0" ?><span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>'
```

but the browser prints

```
{point.key}
```

If I view the page source I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>
```

I am confused. if $v variable has the unparsed xml string or not. Actually I got this problem transfering XML string with JSON as

```
"tooltip": {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}:</td><td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
    },
```

where  I get

```
headerFormat: '{point.key}'`
```

instead of

```
headerFormat:'<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `$v` is printed, the browser just interprets the tags. If you don't want things like `<span>` to be treated as actual HTML, you have to escape the string. The easiest way in PHP is with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
<?php
$v='<?xml version="1.0" ?><span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>';
print htmlspecialchars($v);
?>
```

This will escape all the greater-thans and lesser-thans, etc. and output:

```
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; ?&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size:10px&quot;&gt;{point.key}&lt;/span&gt;&lt;table&gt;
```

which should give you what you want in the browser.